# Messed up keys in vim when running inside tmux

Tags: keyboard, bash, vim, tmux

I have been playing with tmux and I'm loving it. However, there's an annoying issue when running vim inside it.

Somehow the arrow keys get remapped, but only on certain times, like when firing up Command-T, if I try to scroll down the file list, the command is cancelled and I'm thrown into insert mode, and depending on the arrow key I pressed, an A, B, C, or D is inserted.

If I use the arrows to move through a buffer for example, they work properly.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `$TERM` outside `tmux`? What about inside? It sounds like something is going on with application and normal keypad modes.

Comment: Outside tmux: xterm, inside: screen... so if I run `TERM=screen vim` I see the same behavior, so I must fix screen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I found my answer here: [when running screen on OSX, command+r messes up arrow keys in vim across all screens](https://superuser.com/questions/215180/when-running-screen-on-osx-commandr-messes-up-arrow-keys-in-vim-across-all-scre)

The weird thing is I only added ONE mapping to my .vimrc file:

`map <Esc>[B <Down>`

But that single mapping makes ALL the arrow keys work properly...

Comment: Somehow... this was the only solution that worked for me on Centos 6.3

Comment: This makes absolutely no sense to me, but adding a single mapping appears to fix all keys for me as well. Even stranger (at least to me) the direct mapping for the keypress in insert mode doesn't fix it (`map ^[A <Up>` works from pressing Ctrl+V <Up> and deleting the O, `map ^[OA <Up>` from pressing Ctrl+V <Up> and leaving the O doesn't).   I don't get it...but whatever.  My keys now work. Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

I simply added `set -g default-terminal "xterm"` to my .tmux.conf

This made tmux use xterm instead of screen, so life is beautiful and I don't need to worry about stomping on keybindings.

Comment: Better like this `set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"`. Otherwise I couldn't notice when in visual mode due to limited colors.

Comment: I had to combine this with `set -g xterm-keys on`.

Comment: It's worth noting that the man page for tmux says to never set `default-terminal`.  I'm not sure what the ramifications are.

Comment: Given the warning that `default-terminal` should not be set, there is perhaps a better fix from the vim side: [link](http://superuser.com/a/402084/158501).

Comment: Not working in my case...

Comment: @DanStahlke Because by setting `default-terminal` you tell `tmux` which terminal to emulate. But it can't emulate any arbitrary terminal. `tmux` sort of translates between the language your terminal emulator speaks (e.g. `xterm`) and `default-terminal`. The supported values [right now](https://man.archlinux.org/man/community/tmux/tmux.1.en) are `screen`, `tmux` and derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

The xterm and xterm-256color causes the BCE problem. See http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.terminal-emulators.tmux.user/1932.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone happens to get mad with this solutions not working.

Check out that you don't are actually using tmux + vim + [AutoClose](https://github.com/vim-scripts/AutoClose/) vim plugin. Autoclose maps something that causes you having ABCD chars inserted in the previous line!

I just erased the plugin and it's working alright now

Comment: Thank you! This was it for me. I ended up using [this autoclose-plugin](https://github.com/Townk/vim-autoclose/) instead. It provides similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Command-T does something dumb by mapping  when running in a terminal.  It skips the mapping if $TERM is vt100* or xterm*, but that's not a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

For those people that want to move the cursor in command line mode, take a look at [this](http://usevim.com/2012/04/27/command-line-mode/) blog post. I ended up adding eight lines in my vimrc;

```
" Needed for tmux and vim to play nice
" Needed for tmux and vim to play nice
map <Esc>[A <Up>
map <Esc>[B <Down>
map <Esc>[C <Right>
map <Esc>[D <Left>

" Console movement
cmap <Esc>[A <Up>
cmap <Esc>[B <Down>
cmap <Esc>[C <Right>
cmap <Esc>[D <Left>
```