# How to get shift+arrows and ctrl+arrows working in Vim in tmux?

Tags: vim, tmux, modifier-keys

This is all in iTerm2 on OS X.

I used to have

```
export TERM='xterm-256color'
```

in my `.bashrc`. This meant Vim in tmux did use 256 colors.

And once I added

```
set -g xterm-keys on
```

then keyboard shortcuts with modifiers worked fine in Vim. Namely: `shift+left/right` that I mapped to switch Vim tabs, `ctrl+up/down` that I mapped to move ("bubble") lines, and `shift+left/right` which worked out of the box to jump by word in the command-line mode (e.g. when typing something like `:e foo bar baz`).

However, this setup had the problem that the Vim background color only shows behind text, as mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/399296/256-color-support-for-vim-background-in-tmux).

So I removed

```
export TERM='xterm-256color'
```

from my `.bashrc` and instead put this in my `.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

That fixed the Vim background color, but broke the keyboard shortcuts - they do unexpected things (move the cursor, delete text) instead.

By using `ctrl+v` to insert the verbatim output from the key combinations (as described [here](http://blog.yjl.im/2010/01/key-control-code-issue-in-between-vim.html)), I was able to work around it:

```
map [1;5A <C-Up>
map [1;5B <C-Down>
map [1;2D <S-Left>
map [1;2C <S-Right>
cmap [1;2D <S-Left>
cmap [1;2C <S-Right>
```

This makes the shortcuts work, but it doesn't feel like the right solution. Could anyone tell me what's happening here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You need to set the *tmux* window option `xterm-keys` so that *tmux* will pass these keys through to its terminals. You probably want to put this in your `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set-window-option -g xterm-keys on
```

*Vim* will usually automatically set up its handling of these keys when TERM is `xterm`-something, but it skips this since TERM is `screen-256color`. You can manually configure these keys in your `~/.vimrc` like this:

```
if &term =~ '^screen'
    " tmux will send xterm-style keys when its xterm-keys option is on
    execute "set <xUp>=\e[1;*A"
    execute "set <xDown>=\e[1;*B"
    execute "set <xRight>=\e[1;*C"
    execute "set <xLeft>=\e[1;*D"
endif
```

At least that way you do not have to map all the various combinations.

Comment: Thank you! That looks better than what I had, and I appreciate the explanation. One thing that was fixed by what I had, but not by your lines, was that up/down arrows didn't work in the Command-T plugin as described here: http://superuser.com/questions/237751/messed-up-keys-in-vim-when-running-inside-tmux I just added `map <Esc>[B <Down>` from one of the answers. Seems the reason there is some bad assumptions made by the plugin itself.

Comment: Just to be clear, your solution plus `map <Esc>[B <Down>`from that other thread means everything now works fine.

Comment: @HenrikN Could you please clarify what ``map <Esc>[B <Down>`` does? I don't see any difference by adding it to my .vimrc file.

Comment: @Francesco Boccardo: If you follow the link in my previous comment, and then follow the link again from there, you get to https://superuser.com/a/215181 which seems to explain it in excruciating detail :)

Comment: @HenrikN Thanks. So it is probably an OSX related issue, or maybe it's been resolved in these 7 years, because pressing command (control?) + r doesn't mess up the arrow keys in vim in tmux for me (I am on  Linux).

Comment: `xterm-keys` is [not available](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/3.2/CHANGES#L1120) since [2.4](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/3.2/options-table.c#L1079-L1085). | `vim` automatically sets up handling of keys if they exist in the corresponding `terminfo` entry. Or rather, unless they are in the `terminfo` entry, `vim` doesn't know what to expect, and doesn't handle keys it doesn't know. Actually `vim` has some [builtin `termcap` entries](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.4036/src/term.c#L217-L1337)...

Comment: ...Fields from the host entries are added if they're [missing](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.4036/src/term.c#L1742) in the builtin entry (or no builtin entries matched). But I didn't see the keys in the builtin entries. To find out what keys are available: `:set termcap`.

Answer (score 11):

[As explained here](http://snk.tuxfamily.org/log/vim-256color-bce.html), disable **Background Color Erase** (BCE) by clearing the `t_ut` terminal option (run `:set t_ut=` in Vim and then press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to refresh the terminal's display) so that color schemes work properly when Vim is used inside tmux and GNU screen.

This way, you can keep your `TERM` value as `xterm-256color` for proper key detection while also getting proper Vim color scheme rendering too! :-)

Comment: Beautiful! Great detective work.

Comment: This is what I changed exactly: https://github.com/henrik/dotfiles/commit/f8347e465fe9c4b9ff7ea211e2263d6e34ace9dd Colors and modifier keys seem to work well both outside and inside tmux.

Comment: The [docs](https://man.archlinux.org/man/community/tmux/tmux.1.en) says: "The TERM environment variable must be set to ‘screen’ or ‘tmux’ for all programs running inside tmux. New windows will automatically have ‘TERM=screen’ added to their environment, but care must be taken not to reset this in shell start-up files or by the -e option." And: " For tmux to work correctly, this must be set to ‘screen’, ‘tmux’ or a derivative of them."