# vim inside tmux: throws "E388" with <C-Left> in insert mode

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, text-editors, tmux, cursor

I've read that in insert mode in `vim`, one can use `<C-Left>` and `<C-Right>` to move by words. This works for me, but only as far as I don't run `vim` inside `tmux` terminal splitter.

When inside `tmux`, `<C-Left>` instead throws me out of the insert mode and gives an error:

> E388: Couldn't find definition

This error is explained in the help to have something to do with definition searching. However, I don't want any definition to be searched for, I want just to move one word to the left. As well, `<C-Right>` does nothing more than throwing me out of the insert mode, not what I would like.

Reading somewhere that this might be connected to `set (no)esckeys`, I tried it with both settings of this flag, with the very same result. As well, I have seen the answers in [How to get shift+arrows and ctrl+arrows working in Vim in tmux?](https://superuser.com/questions/401926/how-to-get-shiftarrows-and-ctrlarrows-working-in-vim-in-tmux) but they don't appear to help me.

My current `.tmux.conf`:

```
# This File is : ~/.tmux.conf

# use "|" and "-" to do vertical/horizontal splits
# (press CTRL B and then - or |, CTRL D to close it)
unbind %
bind | split-window -h
bind - split-window -v

# use the vim motion keys to move between panes
# (press CTRL B and then h,j,k,l for the move)
bind h select-pane -L
bind j select-pane -D
bind k select-pane -U
bind l select-pane -R

# use vim motion keys while in copy mode
# To copy, press CTRL B and then [, move, space, move, enter.
# To paste, press CTRL B and then ]
setw -g mode-keys vi

# make vim work properly inside tmux
setw -g xterm-keys on
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

And `.vimrc`:

```
" tabs, indentation, line numbering
set ts=4 sts=4 number autoindent sw=4

" sage is python
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.sage set filetype=python

if &term =~ '^screen'
  " Page keys http://sourceforge.net/p/tmux/tmux-code/ci/master/tree/FAQ
  execute "set t_kP=\e[5;*~"
  execute "set t_kN=\e[6;*~"

  " Arrow keys http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/34723
  execute "set <xUp>=\e[1;*A"
  execute "set <xDown>=\e[1;*B"
  execute "set <xRight>=\e[1;*C"
  execute "set <xLeft>=\e[1;*D"
endif
```

Comment: @romainl Ok, so I have seen the two answers in the other thread and as well the post linked in the second of them, but none of the solutions work for me. What can I do now?

Answer (score 1):

Your Vim doesn't correctly detect the `<C-Left>` keycodes sent by the terminal (and probably others, too). Instead, it dissects the codes, `ESC` takes it out of insert mode, and a `[D` then causes the strange error.

You can try fiddling with your `TERM` setting, but in general it's difficult to make special keys (like cursor and function keys) work with modifiers like <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> in the terminal. (Those also don't work for me on Ubuntu with *gnome-terminal*.) The easiest workaround is to use the graphical GVIM instead.

Comment: That's `[D`, by the way.