# How do I create CTRL key bindings in vim when using tmux?

Tags: vim, tmux

I use Vim inside tmux, and have recently added the following to my `.vimrc` file:

```
" easy navigation
nnoremap <C-Left> :tabprevious
nnoremap <C-Right> :tabnext
```

But this seems to have no effect (I press `CTRL+l` or `CTRL+Right` and my cursor just moves as if I hadn't pressed `CTRL` at all). I am guessing that tmux is somehow responsible for this.

I tried adding each (not both) of the following lines to my `.tmux.conf` to no avail:

```
set -g default-terminal "xterm"
set-window-option -g xterm-keys on
```

Surely there's a simple way to pass these commands through to vim?

I read through this post:

[How to get shift+arrows and ctrl+arrows working in Vim in tmux?](https://superuser.com/questions/401926/how-to-get-shiftarrows-and-ctrlarrows-working-in-vim-in-tmux)

and tried adding the following to my `.vimrc`, also with no discernable effect:

```
if &term =~ '^screen'
    " tmux will send xterm-style keys when its xterm-keys option is on
    execute "set <xUp>=\e[1;*A"
    execute "set <xDown>=\e[1;*B"
    execute "set <xRight>=\e[1;*C"
    execute "set <xLeft>=\e[1;*D"
endif
```

I am running vim version 7.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended `TERM` setting for tmux is `screen-256color` and the snippet you added to your `vimrc` works only for a `TERM` that starts with `screen` so you can be sure that code block will never be executed if your `TERM` is `xterm`.

I've been successfully using that very snippet in the past on this machine, *without `set-window-option -g xterm-keys on`,* but for whatever reason it doesn't seem to work anymore for me (I didn't use tmux in the last three months). I wonder what's going on. An iTerm upgrade? A tmux upgrade?

Adding `set-window-option -g xterm-keys on` to my `~/.tmux.conf` fixes the problem.

Anyway, you could directly map the raw sequences produced by `<C-Left>` and `<C-Right>` as a temporary workaround.

```
nnoremap <C-v><C-Left> :tabprevious<CR>
```

should give you something like:

```
nnoremap ^[[D :tabprevious<CR>
```

Comment: `xterm-keys` is [not available](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/3.2/CHANGES#L1120) since [`2.4`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/3.2/options-table.c#L1079-L1085). | I'm not sure I understand how setting `<xLeft>` could help with mapping `<C-Left>`.

Comment: Well, it certainly was available seven years ago, around the time the question was asked. If this solution doesn't work anymore, feel free to post a new *updated* question. As for `<xLeft>`, it is a hack introduced in a 7.x patch to help Vim recognise cursor keys+modifiers in some situations.

Comment: I see, those fields are [already](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.4036/src/term.c#L926-L929) in the `vim`'s builtin `xterm` `termcap` entry. [This part](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.4036/src/term.c#L5492-L5551) separates the key code from modifiers. [Here](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/term.c#L5856) the key code (w/o modifiers) is translated into its non-x* coutnerpart. Then `vim` [looks](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/term.c#L5861) for the keycode + the modifier in a [table](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.4036/src/misc2.c#L798-L886), ...

Comment: ... and if found, the result can match the `<...>` key names. Under `tmux` `TERM` is supposedly different from `xterm`, as such those `set`'s indeed might be needed. If it doesn't work for you, you can give me `TERM`, the key sequence and the escape sequence that don't work, and I'll try to figure it out. | About `xterm-keys` I didn't mean it wasn't needed back then. I just notified you in case you want to update your answer. AFAICU, it's not needed these days (the default).

Comment: Well, thanks for the notification but I will leave the answer as-is and instead upvote yours.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you see the code (e.g. `<C-Left>`) you're using in the section "Terminal keys" of [`:set termcap`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%3Aset), you can't use it right away.

The [docs](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Amap-special-keys) lists 3 ways to map a special key. First in [Insert](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-K) or [Cmdline](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-K) mode press `Ctrl-K`, then the key sequence you want to map (e.g. `Ctrl-K Ctrl-Left`). If it prints `<...>`, you can use that for the left-hand side of your mapping. Or else, prepend it with `<Esc>` (`Ctrl-V Esc`), or use `Ctrl-V Ctrl-Left`. For example, under `tmux` I get `[1;5D` for `Ctrl-Left`, and `<Left>` for `Left`. Which means that for `Left` I can use `<Left>`, and for `Ctrl-Left` I need `^[[1;5D` (`^[` should be **one character**, `Ctrl-V Esc`, and do note the trailing `<CR>`):

```
nnoremap ^[[1;5D <Cmd>tabprevious<CR>
```

Or ([`:h :set-termcap`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%3Aset-termcap)):

```
set <C-Left>=^[[1;5D
nnoremap <C-Left> <Cmd>tabprevious<CR>
```

If you work under different terminals you probably want the second approach:

```
if &term =~ '^screen'
    set <C-Left>=...
elseif &term =~ '^tmux'
    set <C-Left>=...
endif
nnoremap <C-Left> <Cmd>tabprevious<CR>
```

Some keys work with some terminals, but doesn't work with others (when they have no field in the corresponding terminfo entry). Let's take `<S-Left>`, for example. From `:set termcap` not under `tmux` (`TERM=rxvt-unicode-256color`) I can see that it resides in the `t_#4` `termcap` field:

```
t_#4 <S-Left>    ^[[d
```

[`man terminfo`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/core/ncurses/terminfo.5.en) says:

```
key_sleft                   kLFT      #4     shifted left-arrow
                                             key
```

Which means that the `terminfo` name is `kLFT`. Now let's see the value of this field for `TERM=rxvt-unicode-256color` (not under `tmux`), `TERM=screen` (under `tmux`) and `TERM=tmux` (which we might need later):

```
$ infocmp rxvt-unicode-256color | grep kLFT
    kLFT=\E[d, kNXT=\E[6$, kPRV=\E[5$, kRIT=\E[c, ka1=\EOw,

$ infocmp screen | grep kLFT

$ infocmp tmux | grep kLFT
    kHOM=\E[1;2H, kIC=\E[2;2~, kLFT=\E[1;2D, kNXT=\E[6;2~,
```

It's missing in the `screen` `terminfo` entry. To resolve this:

```
if &term =~ '^screen'
    set <S-Left>=...
endif
nnoremap <S-Left> <Cmd>tabprevious<CR>
```

Or (with `vim` we must use `termcap` names):

```
if &term =~ '^screen'
    set t_#4=...
endif
nnoremap <S-Left> <Cmd>tabprevious<CR>
```

Alternatively, you can tell `tmux` to use [its own](https://man.archlinux.org/man/community/tmux/tmux.1.en#default-terminal) `terminfo` entry:

```
set -g default-terminal tmux
```

On a side note, avoid using the `<Esc>` character if possible in your config (or generally in a text file). It's one character that looks like 2. If you e.g. copy it with a mouse, `^[` becomes 2 characters and this way it doesn't work. Particularly in the documentation you can find examples where `^[` is 2 characters, that you can't just copy. This sort of thing is easy to overlook.

And by the way, `xterm-keys` is [not available](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/3.2/CHANGES#L1120) since [`2.4`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/3.2/options-table.c#L1079-L1085).

If it still doesn't work, tell me what you press and the escape sequence it produces (use `Ctrl-V`).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution could be the following:

```
" Note:  Move to the next tab! By Questor
nnoremap <silent> <C-Up> :tabnext<cr>
inoremap <silent> <C-Up> <C-O>:tabnext<cr>
vnoremap <silent> <C-Up> :<C-U>tabnext<cr>v

" Note:  Move to the previous tab! By Questor
nnoremap <silent> <C-Down> :tabprevious<cr>
inoremap <silent> <C-Down> <C-O>:tabprevious<cr>
vnoremap <silent> <C-Down> :<C-U>tabprevious<cr>v
```

Works great for me!

See an example of use in https://github.com/eduardolucioac/groovim/blob/master/.vimrc