# Arrow keys don't work when using mosh remote shell

Tags: vim, mosh

How can I get vim arrow keys to work inside a mosh shell? They used to work for me but after upgrading something (mosh probably) it's broken.

**Arrow keys don't work**

- `mosh 1.2.6` remote shell
- `vim 7.4`
- `ubuntu 14.04`

**Workaround**

```
:set term=builtin_ansi
```

but with this I lose my 256 color display. On a regular ssh session it works fine (where the value of `term` is `xterm-256colors`).

**Works**
(I have this on another machine)

- `mosh 1.2.5` remote shell
- `vim 7.4`
- `ubuntu 16.04`

Comment: I think this is related: https://superuser.com/questions/401926/how-to-get-shiftarrows-and-ctrlarrows-working-in-vim-in-tmux

Answer (score 1):

Not the direct answer to your question how to enable the arrow keys. But Vim standard to move is:

<kbd>h</kbd> – left
<kbd>j</kbd> – down
<kbd>k</kbd> – up 
<kbd>l</kbd> – right

link for moving around in vim: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Moving_around

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm resorting to right now.