# Arrow keys work like option+arrow in terminal in tmux on osx

Tags: macos, keyboard, terminal, tmux

The following setting in `.tmux.conf` breaks arrow keys in terminal in tmux:

```
set-window-option -g xterm-keys on
```

When I disable this setting, then arrow keys work as expected in terminal but then they don't work in Vim.

With this setting, the arrow keys move the cursor word wise as `option+arrow` keys.

The problem occurs both inside Terminal and iterm2.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this same error and fixed it by disabling xterm-keys in my `tmux.conf`:

```
setw -g xterm-keys off
```

I then added the following lines to my `.vimrc` based on this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/964019) to enable the arrow keys to work correctly inside tmux.

```
" Needed for tmux and vim to play nice
nnoremap ^[[A <Up>
nnoremap ^[[B <Down>
nnoremap ^[[D <Left>
nnoremap ^[[C <Right>
```

I added the "^[[A" characters by using Vim's verbatim mode, i.e. pressing Ctrl-v and then the correspodning arrow key.

Finally, I set my tmux `terminal` to `screen256-color` using the following line (also in my `tmux.conf`):

```
set-option -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

Comment: Cannot say that this worked, I had the problem with the arrows like option+arrow only when I was in a remote server, using tmux from my machine. I guess that it was a server problem since I used the terminal of the server. Perhaps I should then of course rather add the setting on the server, but I did not want to touch it. Any comments welcome.

Answer (score 0):

On my macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 the keys are not the same - they are:

```
nnoremap ^[OA <Up>
nnoremap ^[OB <Down>
nnoremap ^[OD <Left> 
nnoremap ^[OC <Right>
```

**NB:** This is not the functionality I was personally looking for and not sure what the tmux command does.

I want to stop the arrows keys opening and performing Mission Control actions. For that, I had to disable the keyboard shortcuts in Preferences.

See: [How can I make ctrl+right/left arrow stop changing Desktops in Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18043/how-can-i-make-ctrlright-left-arrow-stop-changing-desktops-in-lion)