# Line endings messed up in vim when using screen

Tags: vim, gnu-screen

When editing an file in vim it is displayed correctly unless I open vim inside a "screen" window (hope that "window" is the correct term here).

The picture below shows what I mean: I used `:set list` to make EOL visible, but the layout is the same without `:set list` just without the `$` signs.

I did find some online resources (like [this SU question for example](https://superuser.com/q/215180)) but nothing that triggered the "yes, now I get it" sensation.

[image: the same file displayed in vim inside "screen" (left) and outside "screen" (right)]

---

**EDIT:** I am still struggling with that issue and I realise by now that it seems to be somewhat common. It seems to be related to settings made by [`stty`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=stty&sektion=1) (like `onlcr`).

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/316290
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151963

---

Comment: This is a good reason to sudo apt-get install vim - it has a whole different way to show it that I believe you would like better than this, and it works in terminal.

Comment: Are you overriding the TERM environmental variable in any of your startup files? If so, don't.

Comment: I did not first; by now I have `term xterm` in `~./screenrc`, but removing it does not change anything.

Comment: @SDsolar: Sorry, I don't get your point. As far as I can tell I am working in "terminal" and vim was installed using `apt-get install vim-lite`.

Comment: This problem persists (I have removed the `TERM` override from `~/.screenrc` again by now). Pressing `<ctrl>-L` tidies the display BTW.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `tmux` instead of `screen`. That "solved" the problem.